# is it possbile to have same xml file for contextloaderlistner and mvc servet in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

Is it possible to have a same xml file for contextLoaderListener and my mvc servlet. If so, what wil be the scope and how will the web.xml look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have it both in a single xxx-servlet.xml. The web.xml will look as below:

```
<web-app>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/myproject-servlet.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>      
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```